# How to prevent Cucumber feature files from running when they're missing tags?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, webdriver-io

Currently I'm using webdriverIO with Cucumber. All of the tests we want to run are labeled with tags such as '@Regression' in the Feature file when we run them.

However tests that lack a tag and shouldn't be run still launch a webdriver session and then close it without performing any action.

I'm looking for a way to stop this if possible to reduce resource usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber should run only the features that are tagged @Regression. It won't run the ones which are either tagged differently or not tagged at all. Without looking at the code, it would be difficult to pinpoint the issue. Looks like your code is creating unnecessary webdriver session which may not relate to tags. In other words, when you run with just one feature do you see multiple web driver session opening?

However, please check the following gif. I have implemented a solution using Cucumber. Might give you some pointers.
https://nocodebdd.live/running-tags-cuke-example

The same thing done using NoCodeBDD:
https://nocodebdd.live/running-tags-nocodebdd

Disclaimer: I created NoCodeBDD to speed up BDD automation. You can automate BDDs in minutes without code. Basic version is free to use. Would love to get your feedback: https://www.nocodebdd.com/download

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

1. on your package.json, update the run command with **--cucumberOpts.tagExpression**  at the end e.g

> ```
> "test": "wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression",
> ```

now when you run your tests you just run

> npm run tests "@Regression"

All feature files with the tag @Regression will run and everything else will be skipped.